# Accessing secure websites via App

Tags: android

If my app provides a link to a secure website eg a booking system that uses https etc, then are the user's credit card and password details secure in this case ie are the card and password details encrypted when being sent from the mobile phone ?
Also do you need the permssion of the website owner to incorporate such a link into your app. I would have thought the anser is no as it is a publically available website, but I just wanted to make sure.
Thanks very much
Rh

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, everything is encrypted when being sent from the phone. It's like using any other Https connection. You probably should talk to the owner of the website just as a common curtsey.

Comment: Thanks Kurtis, I had begun to modify my question after your initially reply, but you beat me to it and clarified things.  Just to say I am displaying the website by doing startActivity(intent) where the Intent is created with Intent.ACTION_VIEW and the url of the website, so I presume this corresponds to the web browser option you mentioned earlier. Thanks again